# IntelliJ : How to Fix "Code segment has wrong length in class file"

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I have the most frustrating moment with IntelliJ while working on some basic Java.

Let me put it from the start:

1. Before everything and IntelliJ was freshly installed, all code and
   components work just fine.
2. Then I was looking at the settings on how to permanently put word-wrap on my code editor. (turns out you can't, you need to set soft
   wrap every time you open a code).

After some food and returning to my computer, I've been getting this specific error:

```
Error running 'Main': Code segment has wrong length in class file com/intellij/execution/filters/FilterMixin$AdditionalHighlight
```

So I closed the current project and open past projects that never had errors. The same.

```
Error running 'Main': Code segment has wrong length in class file com/intellij/execution/filters/FilterMixin$AdditionalHighlight
```

So, I created a new project, and made this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }

}
```

I cannot possibly imagine any error on that code, but it happened still:

```
Error running 'Main': Code segment has wrong length in class file com/intellij/execution/filters/FilterMixin$AdditionalHighlight
```

This is IntelliJ, not my code obviously... I'm running out of options and I'm starting to believe I can't resolve this without uninstalling the whole IDE and install it clean slate.

Any ideas before I uninstall?

Comment: Do you remember what settings did you change? Please check that right version of compiler is used and file encoding is. to changed.

Comment: The only thing I can recall is that I opened file > settings and searched for the term "word wrap".

Comment: Actually, after starting the computer the next day after a full shut down, the problem no longer persists.  So it doesn't look like this was a setting problem at all either.  This can be bad because if it happens to anyone they won't know what to do until they fully shut down their machine and restart.